# Did Krishna say Karna was the stronger than him and Arjuna?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, karna, kurukshetra

I heard a story about Barbareek, a warrior from the south that could kill both sides of the Kurukshetra war with 2 arrows. In the story Krishna realising he is too great of a warrior tricks him into beheading himself.

That only left Karna, as a stronger warrior, stronger than even Indra and Krishna.

Where in Mahabharata does he admit that?

Comment: Yes that's the one I just read the story on wiki. But the one I heard involved Krishna tricking him, and wiki says he just gave it as charity.

Comment: Where did you make this story? Go read about `Barbareek `, watch old `Sri Krishna` TV serial. He was Dharmic (good) in Nature. He wanted to get liberated fast. So, his grandma told him to go and fight with `Lord Krishna`. Because getting killed by God will get you liberated. Krishna is God. He is everything, He is Karna and He is Arjuna too. Did you never read Mahabharata or Gita? Karna was demi-God. Ramayan has much more powerful warriors even if you combine whole Mahabharata, except Lord Krishna.

Comment: Like `Indrajit` could defeat everyone both Pandavas and Kauravas (except Krishna), in a very short time. Karna was a demigod, yes he was powerful. But he was not powerful than `Bhisma pitama`.  If Krishna fight war could be finished in a few moments.

Comment: Sri krisna TV hagah? I'm talking about the actual text not some interpretation. Arjuna was a demigod also... Krishna is not all powerful and all knowing. If he knew about barbareeks arrows why would he test them hiding the leaf beneath his foot. Why would he go around asking soldiers, barbareek  among them, for whom they will fight. You thing that's just mere frevolity? Is this what you're reducing him to..?

Comment: I don't care about ramajana, it's nothing compared to the epicness of mahabarata

Comment: Also Rama was considered an avatar and he is not all powerful, so was Buddha.. You wouldn't say Buddha could destroy a whole army.. If Krishna fought karna without any tricks karna would beat him..this is not a knock on Krishna, his is probably my favorite character in mahabarata.

Comment: oh, my friend, all that `Sri Krishna TV` shows are in the text Mahabharata, I am telling it from the text. He wanted to get liberated fast. So, his grandma told him to go and fight with Lord Krishna. Because getting killed by God will get you liberated. Krishna is God. He is everything, He is Karna and He is Arjuna too. Did you never read Mahabharata or Gita?

Comment: It's not about epicness. It's about a powerful warrior. `Indrajit ` was way too powerful. He is most powerful being ever born on earth expect any avatar of God. Go read Mahabharta, if you don't believe me. Karna himself respect Krishna a lot. Everyone knows Krishna is God. Even Karna knows that he is supreme God, he respects Lord Krishna and loves his Dharma, even many times call him as supreme God. Then why are you disrespecting Lord Krishna?

Comment: It's written in many texts, getting killed by God. It will lead you to liberation. That is why `Barbareek ` fight with Lord Krishna and wanted to get liberated. Krishna knows the truth yet he questions it because they have too. If you know the future you have to act like that. Let say if some rishi started his meditation, why don't God goes there early and give him boon? God already knows that he will succeed, isn't it? So, why God wait until He or She become eligible to get the boon? It is already in future that he will get the boon than why not early? It is because you have to do the karma.

Comment: Doing Karma will lead to the result. If you want to drink water from an empty glass. You have to go and pore water in it, then drink from it. without this, you won't able to drink water from that empty glass. It is Karma, that you are doing. So, does everyone has to do their Karma. That's why Lord Krishna tested `Barbareek `. Even God has to do his Karma. It is written in Gita. Lord Krishna does not have any desire. But still, he takes Avatar, does illa, `divine play`. Because that is what his Karma is.

Comment: Do you know what Lord Krishna another name? `Mayapati` It means he is Lord of Maya (illusion). This world we live in is Maya, Our Body is Maya, Our relationships are Maya. Even Karna, Arjuna are Maya. We live in this world of illusion. It is also mentioned in Gita, Mahabharta, Vedas, Upanishads and Puranas. So, How can a Maya become more powerful than `Mayapati`. `Karna is just an illusion`. This world is an illusion. How can an illusion, threat to God. It's all illusion that we see. Removing illusion from your life and understanding God. It is enlightenment. Also, `I Love Karna, too`

Comment: Is Buddha also a God? Is Rama a God too? This is what the puranas say... It just pertains to a certain state of consciousness. A stete of being, a level of evolution. Doesn't mean they automatically can erase the universe.. Krishna is in this divine state, he is a being  born in this state. But he doesn't know everything.. And he would be beaten in a head to head match by karna.. How do you compare ramajana and mahabharata characters? There is no basis for that..

Comment: You probably even think Krishna was blue.. So how can you know the guy if you even have misconceptions about his looks..

Comment: Also barbareek wasn't killed by Krishna he cut his own head of..

Comment: By your logic Krishna liberated his evil uncle by killing him..

Comment: I cannot argue with a delusional. Whatever you think, `Lord Krishna` shows Maya by birth. Karna got defeated by Gandharvas, LOL.

Comment: Yes, Buddha and Ram are God. Krishna is blue and in some scriptures, it is said he was black. I don't care about colour or caste. I love his Dharma. That's all I care.

Comment: You care about yoga Maya... You love Maya.. Barbareek cut his own head if.. One of your delusions is that he didn't.. Did Krishnas uncle get liberated upon being killed? Enlighten me..

Comment: Can Buddha being God defeat a superwarrior with celestial weapons? I don't think so..

Comment: You and other iskcon trash are degeneration degrading the great cultular heritage of entire humanity, that is the great mahabharata

Answer (score 3):

Krishna says that even he and Arjuna cannot defeat Karna if Karna had his kavacha (arnour) and kundala (ear rings).

[Source from Mahabharata Drona Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07177.htm)

> **Clad in (natural) coat of mail and decked with his (natural) ear-rings, Karna, who had his senses under control, could singly vanquish the three worlds with the very gods.** Neither Vasava, nor Varuna the lord of the waters, nor Yama, could venture to approach him. **Indeed, if that bull among men had his armour and ear-rings, neither thyself, bending the Gandiva, nor myself, uplifting my discus, called Sudarsana, could vanquish him in battle.** For thy good, Karna was divested of his ear-rings by Sakra with the help of an illusion. Similarly was that subjugator of hostile towns deprived of his (natural) armour.